# Rails comparing values in 2 different collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to compare a value in one collection to see if it's in another?  I'm trying to compare the `current_users.groups` to what's in 
 `@service_requests.unit.groups` and if there is a match I will display just that users service requests.  The below works but it's not what I'm looking for because it will list multiple results.  Basically I'm looking for a way to only show a groups service requests if the current_user is in that group and not show all service requests.

Possibly it's better to remove this from the index view and try and make a scope instead?

```
   <% @service_requests.each do |sr| %>
      <% current_user.groups.each do |group| %>
          <% if sr.unit.group == group.title %>
            <%= group.title %>
            <%= group.description %>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Is possible that a user is in more than a group, thats because you get more than one match? I think you can move the logic in the User model. But better if you can show the relevant part of your schema and associations.

Comment: I have a solution for you, but I have to ask you to add the associations between *ServiceRequest*, *Unit* and the *Group* models. Since my solution is based on the associations. You can add them in a link below if you don't want to clutter your question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `current_users.groups` equals

```
[{name: 'it'}, {name: 'graphics'}, {name: 'marketing'}]
```

and `@service_requests.unit.groups` equals

```
[{name: 'graphics'}, {name: 'test'}]
```

then you can get intersection of these two arrays:

```
current_users.groups & @service_requests.unit.groups # => [{name: 'graphics'}]
```

Also take a look at [this link](http://shortrecipes.blogspot.fr/2006/10/ruby-intersection-of-two-arrays-of.html) for other scenarios.